# Scolltop not working

Tags: jquery

I am adding a class to the the first empty td cell in a container , and i can not get scrollTop to find it. The container will auto scroll , but it will not stop at the empty td cell td.scrollhere

http://jsfiddle.net/dxwd0qp0/97/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var foundOne = false;

    $('#draft_picks_container td').each(function (i, elem) {
        if ($(elem).html().trim() === '&nbsp;' && !foundOne) {
            $(elem).addClass("scrollhere");
            foundOne = true;
            return;
        }
    });

    $('.draft_picks_container').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scrollhere").offset().top - 10
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: It works as expected.

Comment: not working at all , it should scroll to the RED background colored td cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.position()` instead of `.offset()`.
Also you need to calculate the offset of the div.

Here is the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/28985yd4/2/

Comment: ty , that is what i needed thanks for the time to answer